# Java: Can I Code in a String?

Tags: java, string, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing java code given in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057796/executing-java-code-given-in-a-text-file)
>   [using eval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

I have written a Java program, and I was wondering if I can do Java in a String. For example, let's say I have the following:

```
String s = "int i = 1;";
```

In the String above, I have a Java command in it. Can I execute the Command outside the String in my actual program?

Comment: "I'm afraid I can't let you do that" - Hal

Comment: This question is answered in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code

Comment: I'd say, yes & no. Yes you can do dynamic compilation, but, probably not the way you're trying (I'd be happy to be wrong). Take a read through [Generating Java classes dynamically through Java compiler API](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/) to start with (first link off Google)

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you forced to work with Java? Maybe a dynamic language supporting eval is what you are looking for, even though I discourage doing something like that as it makes your code much harder to understand and maintain

Answer (score 3):

You would be able to do this with something like [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).

Comment: I agree, +1. Much safer than compiling and running using the compiler API

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot enter code into a String like that. The `"` symbol essentially delimits the real code from a String.

Once you type in `String xyz =` you are creating a variable, and what comes next needs to be a STring value. Maybe later you can do something with that, but as of now it's not execcutable

You might like to brush up on Strings:

[Java String Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[Quotation marks inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354168/quotation-marks-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

While parsing Java like that might be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code) you could use something like [Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719055/javascript-engine-for-java) to evaluate JavaScript in a string.  This might be a bit outside of what you are asking though.